# DB2 update query with select from different table

Tags: sql, db2

Could someone help me with the following problem?

Lets say I have a database with all vehicles and some kind of radar above the roads that scans the plates. After the radar has scanned the plate it gets added to a DB2 database.

The first table contains all vehicles that are known with a start date, and possibly a end date.
Whenever the color of the car changes, the end date will be filled and a new record will be created with a new start date (this is all done manually)

The second table contains whenever a car drove over the road.

`Cars`:

| ID | Plate | color | Start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 | Blue | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-04 |
| 2 | Name2 | Red | 2021-01-01 | null |
| 3 | Name1 | Purple | 2021-01-05 | null |

`Registrations`:

| ID | Plate | Date | carID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 | 2021-01-01 | null |
| 2 | Name2 | 2021-02-01 | null |
| 3 | Name1 | 2021-03-01 | null |
| 4 | Name1 | 2021-04-01 | null |
| 5 | Name1 | 2021-05-01 | null |

We recently added the carID column, but it needs to get filled, so in the end it should look like this:

`Registrations`:

| ID | Plate | Date | carID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 | 2021-01-01 | 1 |
| 2 | Name2 | 2021-02-01 | 2 |
| 3 | Name1 | 2021-03-01 | 1 |
| 4 | Name1 | 2021-04-01 | 3 |
| 5 | Name1 | 2021-05-01 | 3 |

I was trying to do this with the following query:

```
UPDATE registrations r
SET r.carID = ( 
                SELECT  c.ID 
                FROM cars c
                WHERE c.plate= r.plate 
                AND r.date >= c.start 
                AND r.date < c.end 
                OR c.plate= r.plate 
                AND  r.date >= c.start 
                AND c.end = null
                )
```

The query runs and I get back that 12902 registrations have been updated, however when I check the database nothing actually changed.

Comment: Name1, is that the name of a car owner/driver, or is it a car brand?

Comment: No plate column in any of the table you describe, if it's null in any of the table then the update set 12902 carID to null

Answer (score 3):

I mean you need to set right parentheses in your where statement and replace  `= null` to `is null`:

```
UPDATE registrations r
SET r.carID = ( 
    SELECT  c.ID 
    FROM cars c
    WHERE c.plate = r.plate AND 
          r.date >= c.start AND 
          (r.date <= c.end OR c.end is null)
);
```

[DB2 online fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=7791b4b8426981e84f82425abee8317a)

Comment: Just a tip, https://dbfiddle.uk has both MySQL and DB2, so you easily check if a query works on both.

Comment: DB2 is a very different engine compared to MySQL. I would delete this answer.

Comment: @TheImpaler, you right. Updated query for DB2

Comment: This gives me the following error:  The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES INTO statement is more than one row.. SQLCODE=-811, SQLSTATE=21000, DRIVER=4.16.53

Comment: This is because table Cars have overlaps in start-end dates. You should to fix it or use aggregation query: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=04b84d725591a0a2d55fa8eac899fd2a

Comment: That gives me still the message: SQL Error [21000]: The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES INTO statement is more than one row.. SQLCODE=-811, SQLSTATE=21000, DRIVER=4.16.53